# Change chart bars color in visual studio. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

[image]

How to change those blue colors in design time? i found a method earlier but its only changing the color on the bars and not on the legend.

This chart can show many data depending on the user so i need it to change color for all the data. Thank you

code:

```
   private void loadchartFast()
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BENJOPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
        {          
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold FROM Sales_productholder group by ProductName order by SUM(QtySold) desc", connection); //top selling with desc
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Pieces Sold"].Points.AddXY(read["ProductName"], read["QtySold"]);

            }
            read.Close();
           // chart3.Series["Pieces Sold"].Points[0].Color = Color.LightSeaGreen; ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Palette` property to have different colors:

[image]

Select any of the available Palettes.

In order to add Custom colors, you can add different colors in `PaletteCustomColors` property, and then set `Palette` property to `None`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I added a color in custom palette. how can i use that color in custom palette?